# Android - doubts like fingerprint without sensor

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fingerprint, fingerprinting

I did a lot of research and could not find what I need.
I need to make a fingerprint with devices that do not have fingerprint sensors,
like old devices such as a *Samsung S5* or a *Motorola G3*... devices that do not have a biometric sensor.

I was wondering if I had the touch screen or the camera...
Can there be any way I can do that?
Or some library you can indicate?

Comment: What kind of _devices that do not have fingerprint sensors_? Personal computers?

Answer (score 0):

If the phone has no fingerprint scanner, then one solution is to use an external fingerprint reader; it connects to the phone's USB port. You would also need a fingerprint SDK.

The SDK determines which fingerprint readers that you can use. For example, there is  the [EikonTouch 300](https://www.neurotechnology.com/fingerprint-scanner-upek-eikontouch-300.html) which is supported by the [Neurotechnology SDK](http://neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html), and the [Futronic FS88](https://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs88h.html/) which is supported by the [manufacturer's SDK](https://www.futronic-tech.com/download.html) for android.